# Tree is it Eitz or Illan

Tags: words, hebrew, trees

What is the Diffrence between Eitz and Illan?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

*Etz* is Biblical Hebrew; *ilan* is Rabbinic.

Also, *etz* is ambiguous, since it can mean "tree" or "wood." Thus Rashi (to Gen. 18:4) finds it necessary to gloss תחת העץ as תחת האילן, to make it clear that Avraham was inviting his guests to rest under the shade of a tree rather than under a wooden canopy or something similar.

Comment: It does get a Mention in Daniel

Comment: Actually ilan does appear twice in the Bible, once in Gen 26:34 as the name of Esau's father in law, and again in Dan 4:7.  Esau's in-laws were not Jews, and Daniel is written in Aramaic, which leads to believe that Ilan is actually an Aramaic word, that was adopted into Rabbinic Hebrew.

Comment: Eisav's father-in-law was named "Elon" (with a tzeirei), not "Ilan" (with a chirik).

Comment: R' JD Bleich has said that Ilan is Aramaic not Hebrew (unsurprising it wound up in the Mishna); he goes so far to then state that "Ilana" is a non-Hebrew name and is properly spelled אילנא, just like "Lisa" would be ליסא, the ending-with-heh-for-feminine is only for authentic Hebrew names.

Comment: (From yutorah shiur of his on spelling names in Gittin.)

Comment: Shalom a link?.

Comment: Audio.  I think it's this one?  http://www.yutorah.org/lectures/lecture.cfm/705528/Rabbi_Dr._J._David_Bleich/Gitin_Hebrew_Names

Comment: Arguing over the vowel pointing on Eau's father's name is like saying that Yitzhak is not derivitive(or the same word) as yitzhok(he will laugh).  Vowel points tell us how to read the word, they are not part of the "spelling."

Comment: With Yitzchak the nekudos are the same; with Elon/ilan they are not. Surely you won't claim that any two Hebrew words that have the same spelling are necessarily related etymologically! But anyway, this Elon was a Hittite, and they lived in the Land of Canaan and spoke Hebrew (or something close to it), like all of the Canaanite nations, so there's really no grounds for assuming that his name might be derived from Aramaic. It's far more likely to be related to "el" meaning "strength" (as in ואת אילי הארץ לקח, Ez. 17:13).

Comment: Or "eilon" as in eilon moreh meaning a plane or perhaps a plateau.